# Elixir not giving responce of list_to_bin?

Tags: elixir

```elixir
["257","7"]
|> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
|> Enum.reject(fn x -> x == 0 end)
|> :binary.list_to_bin()
```

Getting error

Need binary Data. If I am using under 255 data it’s giving responses but after 255 not getting any response.

Comment: Why do you "need binary data"? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers are correct, the easiest way here is probably to use [List.to_string/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#to_string/1), which expects unicode charlists:

```
iex> List.to_string([257, 7])
"ā\a"
```

`:binary` expects a list of bytes (integers `< 256`).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of `List.to_string/1`.

Comment: We are using mysql blob and saving binary list over there if you have any solution that can replaced by list to bin please. It's mandatory to use the list to the bin function.

Comment: @NitinKumarDwivedi Saying that it is mandatory when you've been told that the function won't work for your case isn't going to get you a different answer. You have two choices: only use values <=255, or use another function. The one here looks like an ideal choice. It can precisely replace your call to :binary.list_to_bin and give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[`:erlang.list_to_binary/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1) (for which `:binary.list_to_bin/1` is an alias) works with ASCII only. The easiest way to accomplish your goal would be to use [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-into-and-uniq-options) comprehension with a custom binary accumulator, explicitly casting integers to `<<_::utf8>>`.

```elixir
iex|1> for char <- [257, 7], do: <<char :: utf8>>, into: <<>>
"ā\a"
```

Answer (score 0):

An Elixir binary is a string of ASCII characters. The values therefore need to be `<=255`.

```
iex> [32, 54] |> :binary.list_to_bin()
" 6"
```

Comment: But i need save ,<255 value